# I've gotten this bonsai tree 2 days ago and I'm having trouble identifying this tree

Tags: trees, leaves, bonsai

[image]I have searched all bonsai tree related websites and still have not found the type of bonsai it is because of the color and shape of the leaves

Comment: Are the leaves prickly at all?

Comment: This is indeed not a very common type of bonsai, I have never seen it before. Do you know if it is from tropical or temperate climate?